# Retrieve Balance in MT4 using AutoIt

Tags: autoit, metatrader4

I'm trying to get the values of a `listView` of the software called MetaTrader Terminal 4 ( for details, ref. **[metatrader4](/questions/tagged/metatrader4)** ).

I was able to retrieve the number of lines, but that's all, not the actual item texts ( and I've tried that many **many** ways ).

How is it that it is so hard to retrieve values from an external program?

**Are there other ways to do so?**

```
$Win2 = WinGetHandle( "2000100748" , "EURAUD") ;get window handle
ConsoleWrite("$Win2="&$Win2&@lf)
$Ctl2 = ControlGetHandle ($Win2,"",'[CLASS:SysListView32; INSTANCE:4]') ;get treeview inside $Win2 handle
ConsoleWrite("$Ctl2="&$Ctl2&@lf)

$aa = ControlListView($Win2, "", "[CLASS:SysListView32; INSTANCE:4]", "Selectall")
MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL,"", $aa)

$a =  _GUICtrlListView_GetItemCount($Ctl2)
MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL,"", $a)

$b = _GUICtrlListView_FindText ($Ctl2,"Volume")
MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL,"", $b)
```

[image]

**EDIT**: when using **`_GUICtrlListView_GetItemTextString($Ctl2, $i)`**
I get "`|||||||`" as a result

thanks

Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### May use `MQL4` tools available to help better automate the task:

The MetaTrader Terminal 4 has a built-in programming language ( **`MQL4`** ). That provides all possible automation tools one may need, incl. the Account profit, balance and all other details.

Based on one's need, the **`double AccountBalance()`** can get

- **printed** `Print( "Account balance = ", AccountBalance() );`
- **displayed** `Comment( "Account balance = ", AccountBalance() );` in graph-area
- **stored**  `FileWrite( aFileHANDLE, "Account balance = ", AccountBalance() );`
- **sent**   `SendMail( "Account balance = " + (string) AccountBalance() ) );`
  by email

whichever representation of the account balance detail is easier for one's automation needs, be it using an AutoIt or other tools.